# How to make query to select data as I want

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables.

Table1

```
 item  desc
 1     item1
 2     item2
 3     item3
```

Table2:

```
 item2  desc2
 1     item1
 2     item2
 3     item3
```

Table3:

```
 item1  item2  quantity
 1      1      5
 1      2      4 
 2      2      3
 3      1      10
```

Now in table 3, column 1 (item1) is foreign key to Table1 and column 2 (item2) is foreign key to Table2. Now I want to write a query to fetch records like it crosss join all possible combination if some combination for some records does exist it shows their quantity 0 like this.

I want result like this:

```
 item1  item2  quantity
 1      1      5
 1      2      4 
 1      3      0
 2      2      3
 2      1      0
 2      3      0
 3      1      10
 3      2      0
 3      3      0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming tables named @tab1, @tab2 and @tab3, you can do:

```
SELECT b.item, b.item2, IsNull(a.quantity, 0) as quantity
FROM (SELECT item, item2 FROM @tab1 CROSS APPLY @tab2) b
FULL OUTER JOIN @tab3 a ON a.item1 = b.item AND a.item2 = b.item2
```

Comment: Why CROSS APPLY and not simply CROSS JOIN?

Answer (score 2):

Use `cross join`

```
select t1.item as Item1, t2.item as Item2, coalesce(t3.quantity, 0) as quantity
from table1 t1 cross join 
     table2 t2 left join 
     table3 t3 
     on t3.item1 = t1.item and t3.item2 = t2.item
order by t1.item, t3.quantity desc, t2.item;
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple :)

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hMrsY3aJFK18BTJe36NbPb/0)

```
SELECT t1.item, t2.item2, IFNULL(t3.quantity, 0) as quantity
FROM
    t1  JOIN t2
    LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.item1 = t1.item AND t3.item2 = t2.item2
```

`JOIN` without `ON` -> joins everything to everything

`LEFT JOIN` adds data to rows (in this case `quantity`) but leaves rows intact